# (Google Documents) Way to create custom documents based on certain input variables?

Tags: google-docs, document, doc

Is there a way to have a paragraph of text get spit out when you have a certain input, from say a google questionnaire?

And make it so you could have say 5 inputs, and it would spit out 5 paragraphs of information, into one document?

For example:

If someone fills out a questionnaire where the first question is year of birth, the tool would spit out the first paragraph with a description of what the year they were born was like.

Second question would be their birth country, the tool would place a paragraph of text about their birth country into the document.

etc etc

Many thanks in advance for any help

Comment: If I understand correctly, what you are trying to do is to read a spreadsheet containing the responses of a Google Form, and create Google Docs based in the 5 inputs from the 5 questions of the Google Form, am I correct?

Comment: @FernandoLara yes that is correct

Comment: If this answered your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon). By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [How to accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to create documents using a specific criteria based in form responses. I created the following sample script using Google Apps Script so you can get the idea:

```
function docCreation() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
  var range = ss.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues().reverse(); //reverses the array to get the last value in the first position
  var doc = DocumentApp.create("Testing doc"); // You can change the name to match a username or any other variable instead
  switch (getMonth(values[0][1].toString())) {
  case 'Aug':
    doc.getBody().appendParagraph("This is a sample body for August");
    break;
  case 'Jul':
    doc.getBody().appendParagraph("This is a sample body for July");
    break;
  }
}
 // Second function that returns the month value of the date introduced by the user
// I separated it because it is not that relevant to the main goal
function getMonth(val){
  var month = val.split(" ");
  return month[1];
}
```

It is a very simple script that checks if the month of the date introduced by the user is August or July, and if so, it creates a doc with a simple text as paragraph.

The script is bounded to the Google Sheet of the form responses and you can create a trigger so that every time a user fills out the form, the script starts running to create the needed documents. Now as I mentioned, this is just a sample, and the logic and docs format would depend on your specific needs and usage.

References:

- [Class Body](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body)
- [Create document](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document-app#createname)